# In React while submitting a sign in, am getting my password and email in (Localhost)URL as query string?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express, react-redux, query-string

After running my project in Localhost and and giving my information's for signin , am getting this in my URL

`http://localhost:3000/?email-address=roopa%40gmail.com&password=roopa3`

and i also checked for "onClick" in my events, but everything is ok..

```
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('emailchanged')
    this.setState({signinEmail: event.target.value})
    }

    onPasswordchange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('passwordchanged')
    this.setState({signinPassword: event.target.value})
    }

    onSubmitSignin = () => {
        console.log('entered onsubmitsignin..') // after this console msg again my localhost redirects me to a new signin page which giving inputs to URL as query strings 
        fetch('http://localhost:8050/signinpage/', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.signinEmail,
                password: this.state.signinPassword
            })
        })
        .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.status);
                return response.json();
                })
        .then(res => {
            if(res.ok){
                this.props.onRoutechange('Home'); 
            }
            else if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP status " + res.status);
            }
        })
    }
```

I don't need my inputs to show as query string here..!

Comment: Why is there no `event.preventDefault();` for `onSubmitSignin` do you know what preventDefault does?

Comment: well it looks like it is also going to a different URL - port `3000` instead of what you have in your code - port `8050`

Comment: I have sort out something and now, the error's are   `POST http://localhost:8050/signinpage/ 400 (Bad Request)`   `Uncaught (in promise) Error: HTTP status undefined`  on submitting the signin